# assign value to hidden ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

for some reason I need to assign the same value in two input. means I have to set the value of the variable `first` in `second` without the need for the user to write it himself

model

```
export class Exp{

    id: number;
    first: any;
    second: any;

}
```

html

```
    <label>enter value of first :</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="exp.first" class="form-control">

     <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="exp.second" class="form-control">

           <button (click)="add()">add</button>
```

ts

```
   add(){
    this.myService.add(this.exp).subscribe(
       data => {this.exp=data;}, 
       error => {console.log('error');}
     );

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma614815626433166?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Initially, you can set a template reference variable to the first input, receiving the `ngModel` directive:

```
<input type="text" #first="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="exp.first" class="form-control">
```

After that, you can grab a reference to that control on typescript, subscribe to its changes and copy it to `second` in model:

```js
@ViewChild('first') _ngModelFirst: NgModel;

// Best practice: let's unsubscribe from all observables
// when this component is destroyed
private _destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

exp: Exp = {
  id: 1,
  first: '',
  second: ''
};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this._ngModelFirst.valueChanges
    // Best practice: this pipe is just to finish the subscription
    // when this._destroy$ emits
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
    .subscribe((value: string | null) => {
      this.exp.second = value;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this._destroy$ && !this._destroy$) {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works and it's a nice solution if you really have to set the value in a hidden input. Otherwise `this.exp.second = this.exp.first` would do the trick in your `add` method.

Comment: @eze, the input is **hidden**... what you expected to see? You have to open the developer tools in your browser to see the value is set to the hidden input.